# What instrument produces a triangle wave?

Tags: theory, instruments

I am currently researching the graphs of various instruments as part of a school project and am trying to figure out which instruments produce which wave forms.

I have read the answers to a similar question entitled "Examples of acoustic instruments producing sounds very close to pure square, triangle or sawtooth waves". However, it appears to me that no one gave an example for the triangle wave form. Any ideas?

Comment: I think OP sufficiently explains why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: That linked question does include triangle wave sources. Closing as dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangle wave is the most similar to a sine wave that the majority of analog synths can get (not counting filter used as an oscillator), and a triangle can be made even closer to a sine using a filter. Lip reed and whistle woodwinds like flute, piccolo, tin whistle, and recorder are fairly close to sine waves.

If I were working on a flute patch I'd start by filtering a single triangle wave and then add a bit of noise to it for the breath sound.